# reference value only(no background fill, etc.) of a cell in another worksheet in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, row

I have a workbook in Excel 2010 with 2 worksheets.

Sheet 1 has rows of data sorted by dates with different numbers of rows for each date.
[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2 calculates the daily averages based on the dates and puts them on individual rows,(1 row for each date) using formula =Sheet1!A5 which works fine but the row band color is copied too so Sheet 2 looks poorly formatted with regards to the row banding which seems to be inherited with reference.

[image: Sheet 2]

How can I retain the uniform banding in sheet 2 and keep the fill color from being copied along with the cell's data?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand Your question right: You dont want the cells to be colored in Sheet 2, but You want the values to be the same as in Sheet 1.

Judging by the pictures You have provided there is a Conditional formatting on Sheet 1. I think that You copied Sheet 2 from Sheet 1, using right click and Copy or move and  the formatting was copied as well. On Sheet 2 under Conditional formatting delete or edit the current formatting rules. Make sure to select "This Table". That way You can see all the rules on Sheet 2, and its easier to delete or edit.

Formulas in Excel can't bring colors, so it has nothing to do with that.